# Inconsistent CSS animation with the details tag

Tags: css, css-animations

The animation accompanying the opening of the details element is rendered inconsistently. It may open smoothly using the "sweep" animation, or open immediately with no animation at all. This can be seen when opening and closing details, waiting several seconds, and opening it again. In my case, the animation is consistent only when clicking the element in quick succession.

I would like details to open smoothly every time with CSS. I am using Chrome.

```css
.information {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0x;
    color: #000;
    width: 332px;
}

.details1 {
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 400px;
}

.details1[open] summary ~ * {
  animation: sweep .2s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sweep {
  0%    {opacity: 0; margin-top: 10px}
  100%  {opacity: 1; margin-top: 0px}
}
```

```html
<center><div class="maindiv" style="position: relative;"><details class="details1 "><summary class="summary1"><span class="ring">◯</span></summary><div class="information">

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
</div></details></center></div></center></details></div></details></center>
```

Comment: Note that the `<center>` tag has been obsolete for maybe 20 years. Also, no browser has needed the `-webkit` vendor prefix in a long, long time.